# Is it possible to have an initial zoom for WebView

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I wonder if there was a way to zoom the websites automatically so the user would not have to. If there is, How do I do it? I use the plugin [webview_flutter: ^2.0.8](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) in my `pubspec.yaml`

I simply wish to be able to display part of a website but not all of it for the user. Is this possible?

This is my current code:

```dart
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFCFCFC),
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('AMIHAN',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 28.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            letterSpacing: 2.5,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
        color: Colors.grey,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              const SizedBox(height: 20,),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: WebView(
                  initialUrl: 'my 1st url',
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20),
              Container(
                height: 200,
                width: 200,
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: WebView(
                  initialUrl: 'my 2nd url',
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my current output The website contents are far too small and unreadable. I have made the background grey to see the webview easier.

[image: Two webviews are displayed each with one graph]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the webview_flutter plugin, you can use the initialScale parameter to set the initial zoom level for the web view.

**for example  initial zoom level to 150%:**

This will automatically zoom the website to 150% of its original size when it loads in the web view. You can adjust the initialScale value as per your need .

If you want to display only part of the website, you can use the javascriptMode parameter to disable JavaScript in the web view and the userAgent parameter to specify a custom user agent string. This will prevent the website from running any scripts or expanding to fill the full screen.

WebView(
initialScale: 150,
initialUrl: "https://www.example.com",
javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
userAgent: "The Part you want to restrict",
)

Comment: 'initial scale' doesn't seem to work. I mean it doesn't seem to be part of WebView. Perhaps I am using the wrong version of the plugin?

 Also, I do not understand how userAgent would work. I tried searching for it but as far as I've seen it's only for when the app doesn't load on different devices based on screen size.

I am sorry. I am very new to flutter. I would appreciate more explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found a solution although may not have been the most efficient. I simply made a custom web view where the HTML code is displaying the website. it was much easier to customize it that way.